# How to show all result on buffer in OCaml's tuareg mode

Tags: ocaml, tuareg

In OCaml's tuareg mode, I cat't see the execution result if the result is big as below.

```
# function ();;
- : tree_t =
Node (Node (Node (Node (Node (Node (Node
             (Node (Node (Node (Empty, 1, Empty), 2, Empty), 3,
      ...), 
    ...),
  ...))
```

I cat't see the execution result because some parts are showed by "...". 
How can I see all result on buffer in OCaml's tuareg mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `print_depth` and `print_length` directives to increase the amount of printed data, e.g.,

```
# #print_depth 100500;;
```

Comment: Thank you! I could see all the result by your answer!